# Intermediate Value Property and Discontinuous Functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

This is a general question to which I need help finding a concrete example so that I may understand the concept/strategy better, and any help will be greatly appreciated.

If given a function $F$ that is not continuous, how can I show that the given function satisfies the intermediate value property? A hint that was given by the Professor was to find an auxiliary function $f$ such that $f'=F$.

I know that all continuous functions have the intermediate value property (Darboux's property), and from reading around I know that all derivatives have the Darboux property, even the derivatives that are not continuous.

Here is what I could make sense of the Professor's hint:

If I could find a suitable function $f$ which was differentiable, and $f'=F$, the derivative would have the intermediate value theorem (since all derivatives have the intermediate value property), and thus the original discontinuous function $F$ would also have the intermediate value theorem.

Can anyone please tell me if my reasoning is correct and/or please provide me with a discontinuous function that I can practice on (or perhaps direct me to another question with such a function that I may have overlooked)?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: "If given a function F that is not continuous, how can I show that the given function satisfies the intermediate value property?"  You can't, because that's often false.  From later context, perhaps you mean to ask, "How can I find an example of a function $F$ that is discontinuous but satisfies the intermediate value property, and how can I show that it has these properties?"  Unless you were given the explicit function $F$, in which case, please share.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Sorry, I realized where the confusion came about, and, no, I wasn't given a specific function. I think this perhaps goes along with what I was thinking better: If I am given a discontinuous function $F$ and am told to show that it has the IVP *(which is a clear indicator that it has the property and my task is to prove it)* how can I go about doing this? (Preferably using the Professor's hint. If you have a function in mind like this I'd be glad to hear/see it)

Comment: In a nutshell you want an example of $f$ differentiable with $f'$ not continuous. Can you provide that? Such an example might be mentioned earlier on in your notes...

Comment: There are already several threads concerning Darboux functions, which are not continuous; so they might be somewhat interesting for you.
For example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21812/can-we-construct-a-function-f-mathbbr-rightarrow-mathbbr-such-that-it-h) or
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186427/function-whose-image-of-every-open-interval-is-infty-infty); you can also find other links in answers and comments there.

Comment: You can probably find a several examples of derivatives, which are not continuous, for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239690/a-function-not-continuous-but-sill-has-antiderivative-necessary-and-sufficient).

Comment: @MartinSleziak okay, I looked at the links you provided and think I understood things a little better. So, say I was given a function $F$ and $F=- \cos(1/x)+2x \sin(1/x)$ and was told to show that it had the IVP. This is what I would do(?): Observe that the function $F$ is not continuous at $x=0$. Let $f(x)=x^2 \sin(1/x)$ when $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$, the derivative of this function is $f'(x)=- \cos(1/x)+2x \sin(1/x)$ and because all derivatives have the IVP, the original function, $F(x)$, must also contain the IVP.

Comment: @user66807 I did not want to clutter this page with too many comments, so I tried to reply [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8662) instead.

Comment: @Did is the function I mentioned in the comments the kind of example you are talking about?

Comment: @user66807 I mentioned no "kind of example" hence I guess the answer to your query is "no"...

Comment: @Did you said "In a nutshell you want an example of $f$ differentiable with $f′$ not continuous. Can you provide that?" my $f$ is $f(x)=x^2 \sin(1/x)$ and its derivative is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: It seems @MartinSleziak is willing to help you in chat, so, if you will excuse me... (Simply, when you are clear about a solution, do not forget to post it as an answer.)

Comment: @Did sorry if I was bothering you, I entered the chat but he was not there. If I get a solution I will be sure to post it.

Answer (score 10):

If I understood the OP correctly, he wants some simple examples of functions, which are not continuous and they have Darboux property. (He wants to practice showing that a function has intermediate value property on some concrete examples.)

I've given a few examples. I have made this post CW, so feel free to add further examples.

---

**Functions which are not continuous, but are derivatives:**

$f(x)=
  \begin{cases}
    \sin\frac1x, & x\ne 0, \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$

$g(x)=
  \begin{cases}
    2x\cos\frac1x+\sin\frac1x, & x\ne 0, \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$

$h(x)=
  \begin{cases}
    2x\sin\frac1{x^2}-2\frac1x\cos\frac1{x^2}, & x\ne 0, \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$

The functions $f(x)$, $g(x)$ are $h(x)$ are from the book Van Rooij-Schikhof: A Second Course in Real Analysis (in the [Introduction](http://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA4).).

---

**Functions which are not continuous, but have Darboux property (intermediate value property):**

$f_2(x)=
  \begin{cases}
    \sin\frac1x, & x\ne 0, \\
    1 & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$

Again from the book Van Rooij-Schikhof: A Second Course in Real Analysis (in the [Introduction](http://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA4).).

Comment: Defined in such way $f(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: @user48672 Neither of the functions mentioned in this post is continuous.

Comment: All of these functions have sin/cos of $\frac1x$. Are there any functions that can be "drawn" by pen, or otherwise simpler?

Comment: If you want function to be discontinuous at some point $x$, [oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics)) at this point has to be non-zero. If we also want IVP, this implies that all values from some interval will be attained arbitrarily close to $x$. (And, consequently, those values will be attained infinitely many times.) So I do not expect functions with these properties that are much "easier to sketch" than this. (If needed, we can discuss this a bit more in the [calculus chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14150/2019/11/8) some time.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that's *nowhere* continuous but satisfies the Darboux property.

$$\begin{align}f:\mathbb{R}&\to[0,1]\\\\ \overline{a_1a_2\cdots a_r.a_{r+1}a_{r+2}\cdots}_\textbf{2}&\mapsto\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1+...+a_n}{n}\end{align}$$

Here $\overline{a_1a_2\cdots a_r.a_{r+1}a_{r+2}\cdots}_\textbf{2}$ is the unique binary non-degenerate representation of an arbitrary real number. (By non-degenerate I mean that the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ does not end in an infinite array of ones.)

The Darboux property for $f$ is derived from the fact that $f(I)=[0,1]$ for every open interval $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$; and $f$ is discontinuous everywhere. You may care to check both properties.

Comment: For those who might be interested, more about the possible pathology of functions with the Darboux property can can be found at: [Is there a different name for strongly Darboux functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/137986/13130) **AND** [this 3 December 2000 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/fvIACHSfC00/m/VSSFudeSIHEJ) **AND** [*Darboux continuity*](http://eudml.org/doc/146526;jsessionid=98522A06CD68A44763F32C1354F068AB) by Andrew Michael Bruckner and Jack Gary Ceder (1965).